# ThreeJS How to set the position of the OrbitControls

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm storing the position of the OrbitControls using .getAzimuthalAngle() and .getPolarAngle() and at a later date I want to be able to set getAzimuthalAngle and getPolarAngle but with slightly different values.

The reason I'm using getAzimuthalAngle and getPolarAngle is because I need to work out the percentage of the rotation, e.g. if's 180° that would be 50%. As in the background I'm setting the position of a 2D map to mirror the same location. I've got it working one way, but as I can't set the position of the OrbitControls, I'm a stuck..

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to hack a solution in by duplicating the OrbitControl Update function and setting theta and phi values directly (rather than in increments as the update function)

```
this.setPhiTheta = function(t, p) {
    var position = this.object.position;

    offset.copy( position ).sub( this.target );

    // rotate offset to "y-axis-is-up" space
    offset.applyQuaternion( quat );

    // angle from z-axis around y-axis

    theta = Math.atan2( offset.x, offset.z );

    // angle from y-axis

    phi = Math.atan2( Math.sqrt( offset.x * offset.x + offset.z * offset.z ), offset.y );

    if ( this.autoRotate && state === STATE.NONE ) {

        this.rotateLeft( getAutoRotationAngle() );

    }

    /*theta = 3.105;
    phi = 1.48;*/
    theta = t;
    phi = p
    //console.log("theta " + theta)
    // restrict theta to be between desired limits
    theta = Math.max( this.minAzimuthAngle, Math.min( this.maxAzimuthAngle, theta ) );

    // restrict phi to be between desired limits
    phi = Math.max( this.minPolarAngle, Math.min( this.maxPolarAngle, phi ) );

    // restrict phi to be betwee EPS and PI-EPS
    phi = Math.max( EPS, Math.min( Math.PI - EPS, phi ) );

    var radius = offset.length() * scale;

    // restrict radius to be between desired limits
    radius = Math.max( this.minDistance, Math.min( this.maxDistance, radius ) );

    // move target to panned location
    this.target.add( pan );

    offset.x = radius * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.sin( theta );
    offset.y = radius * Math.cos( phi );
    offset.z = radius * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.cos( theta );

    // rotate offset back to "camera-up-vector-is-up" space
    offset.applyQuaternion( quatInverse );

    position.copy( this.target ).add( offset );

    this.object.lookAt( this.target );

    //thetaDelta /= 1.2;
    //phiDelta /= 1.2;
    scale = 1;
    pan.set( 0, 0, 0 );

    // update condition is:
    // min(camera displacement, camera rotation in radians)^2 > EPS
    // using small-angle approximation cos(x/2) = 1 - x^2 / 8

    if ( lastPosition.distanceToSquared( this.object.position ) > EPS
        || 8 * (1 - lastQuaternion.dot(this.object.quaternion)) > EPS ) {

        this.dispatchEvent( changeEvent );

        lastPosition.copy( this.object.position );
        lastQuaternion.copy (this.object.quaternion );

    }
}
```

Comment: However this doesn't animate, which is fine for the moment but will need to find a way in a couple of days